# Yii2 Pass multiple SQL row result to view

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am stuck on a problem regarding a query I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT o.name, p.org_id as organization_ID, COUNT(p.id) FROM publications AS p JOIN organizations as o WHERE o.id = p.org_id GROUP BY org_id
```

Which prints out all my data as I want them.

When I go back to Yii2 to make this query, I have some hesitations.

```
$totalpubperorg = Publication::find()->select(['org_id, COUNT(id)'])->from('publications')->join('INNER JOIN','organizations','publications.org_id = organizations.id')->groupBy('org_id');
```

On my view this gives me:

```
NULL NULL NULL array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "org_id, COUNT(id)" } NULL NULL array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "publications" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "org_id" } array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "INNER JOIN" [1]=> string(13) "organizations" [2]=> string(38) "publications.org_id = organizations.id" } } NULL NULL NULL array(0) { } NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL bool(false) string(22) "app\models\Publication" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

I am passing the result of the query on the view like this:

```
        return $this->render('pupbs',
    [
        'totalpubperorg' => $totalpubperorg
    ]);
```

and I thought I could simply show each result using a foreach loop:

```
        <?php
        foreach($totalpubperorg as $tppo){
            var_dump($tppo);
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the call to the `all()` method that will return the models from the query:

```php
 foreach($totalpubperorg->all() as $tppo){
     var_dump($tppo);
 }
```

Just give a look at official documentation: [Querying data](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#querying-data)

Comment: still throws a blob of data. But not the data I need.
I changed my original query string to: 
`$totalpubperorg = Publication::find()->select(['o.name, p.org_id, COUNT(p.id)'])->from('publications AS p')->join('JOIN','organizations AS o','p.org_id = o.id')->groupBy('p.org_id')->**all();**` but still cannot get o.name from the joined table. _Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\Publication::name_

Comment: That's because Yii is trying to insert the query result into a Publication model. Add an `asArray()` call before the `all()` and you will  see it will work. But there are two other "more final" solutions: 1. Create a custom model with the attributes you wan't to return from the query; or 2. Instead of `Publication::find()`  use `(new \yii\db\Query)`.